# Difference between tree declarations?

Tags: haskell

What's the difference between

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node (a, Tree a, Tree a) deriving Show
```

and

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) deriving Show
```

Note: parenthesis for node

Comment: Note also that `Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)` will be better than either if an inorder traversal of the tree is especially meaningful (e.g., for a search tree), as this will let you use `deriving (Foldable, Traversable)` and get the results you probably want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a difference: in the first one `Node` is a constructor with one field, a tuple. This means that when we give it a type it has the form `Node :: (a, Tree a, Tree a) -> Tree a`, a function of one directly to a tree. The latter is a constructor with 3 fields so the constructor is typed with an appropriate curried function.

Now it may appear that these are equivalent but there's a significant difference in how much indirection there is in these two declarations. In the first we have a pointer to a tuple of 3 pointers. In the second we have 3 pointers directly in the constructor. This can have some impact on efficiency (as indirection always does) and also introduces an extra value into the first definition, `Node undefined` (or more generally speaking, `Node _|_`) which doesn't have a clear equivalent in the latter.

The reason for this is that each level of indirection in Haskell gives us the ability construct a new funky pseudo value where the outermost wrapper evaluates but the indirection (which provides laziness) points to a divergent thunk. If you looked at these in a strict language you'd find them to be isomorphic but strictly speaking they ought to have different denotations in models of Haskell.

For idiomatic and more efficient code, opt for the latter.